# modificar array desde distintos archivos php

Tags: php

Estoy simulando un sistema de parking básico y en la opción de aparcar, tengo 2 arrays (plaza grande, plaza chica) inicializados a false, si el usuario elige desde un formulario coche grande, el sistema aparca y cambia el valor de la plaza a true de manera que esa plaza ya no esta disponible. Mi problema es que o logro mantener el valor del array una vez modificado, cada vez que el usuario hace click deberían acumularse los true, dejando menos plazas disponibles pero no logro hacerlo...no logro mantener los valores de los array, aunque los declare static y utilice sesiones, no se que estoy haciendo mal...

index.php

```
    <?php
     session_start();

    static $totalPlazasChico = array();
    static $totalPlazasGrande = array();

     for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { $totalPlazasChico[$i] = false; } //Total de plazas chicas
     for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { $totalPlazasGrande[$i] = false; } //Total de plazas grandes

    if (!isset($_SESSION['plazaChica']) && !isset($_SESSION['plazaGrande'])){

    $_SESSION['plazaChica'] = $totalPlazasChico;   //variables de sesion para gestionar los arrays
    $_SESSION['plazaGrande'] = $totalPlazasGrande;
```

}

```
     if (!isset($_REQUEST['btn_ver'])) {   //envio del formulario

      } else {

      $accion = $_REQUEST['parking'];  //aparca || retira

      if ($accion == "aparca") {
        header("Location:aparca.php");     //Desde aquí gestiono los arrays    

       } else {
          header("Location:retira.php");
           }
       }
  ?>
```

aparca.php:

```
    <?php
     session_start();

     $grandes = $_SESSION['plazaGrande'];
     $chicos = $_SESSION['plazaChica'];

     if (!isset($_REQUEST['btn_aparca'])) {   //envío del formulario

    echo 'error';

     }

    $accion = $_REQUEST['aparcar']; //radiobutton

    if($accion == "grande"){

     for ( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
      
        if(!$grandes[$i]){      //Si $i no es true
            break;      //Primera posición vacía
        }
     }
         if($i < 14){
            $grandes[$i] = true;
          
         }else{ echo 'no hay lugar';
        
         }        
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: En aparca.php debieras guardar el array modificado en la sesión.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te pasa es normal. Cada vez que lanzas una Request al servidor el código PHP inicia de nuevo, no puedes conservar valores entre ejecuciones diferentes de PHP.

Para eso deberías guardar el cambio en la base de datos. Aparte la sesión caducara al cabo de un tiempo y volverás a empezar de 0. Y lo de declarar static no tiene nada que ver con todo esto.

Si el usuario interactúa usando su navegador, eso se hace por lado de cliente (Javascript) no servidor (PHP). Cuando envías Request a PHP debe ser sólo para "serializar" la información. Serializar significa guardarlo en algún sitio donde se guarde a largo plazo, como en una base de datos o fichero de texto. Pero no puedes conservar el valor entre ejecuciones de php.

Para hacer esto te podrías basar en como funciona el Cart (Carrito) de una tienda. Cada usuario tiene asignado un carrito, que es un listado de productos, y esto se guarda en base de datos.

Tienes dos opciones, editar todo desde la web manteniendo los valores en Javascript, y al guardar enviar por Ajax toda la información a PHP y ahi guardarlo todo en DB, o cada vez que el usuario hace un cambio enviar una request que guarde ese cambio en la DB.